# Regex to ignore HTML tags

Tags: regex

In this scenario, I would like to capture dgdhyt2464t6ubvf through regex. Please can you help me. Thank you so much!

```
<br />For API key "fnt56urkehicdvd", use API key secret:
<br />
<br />  dgdhyt2464t6ubvf
<br />
<br />Note that it's normal to
```

So far, I have this, but it is not getting past the `<br />`:

```
use API key secret:[\s]+</br>*(.*)[\s]+\sNote
```

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Is it always the third line? For regex to work there has to be some sort of pattern. What is the pattern?

Comment: With the necessary [obligatory comment link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1#comment1612336_1732454).

Comment: yes, always on the third line. I always get an email that specifies the key and secret like this on the third line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "<br />For API key \"fnt56urkehicdvd\", use API key secret:" +
        "<br /><br />  dgdhyt2464t6ubvf<br /><br />Note that it's normal to";
    String[] temp = test.split("\\<br /\\>");
    System.out.println(temp[3].trim());
}
```

Output:

> dgdhyt2464t6ubvf

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your regex.

1. The `*` after the `</br>` only makes the `>` optional. My guess is that you wanted the whole `</br>` to be optional.
2. `</br>` should be `<br />`. There is no `</br>` in the text, so the regex won't find anything. By the way, `<br */>` is better, since the space isn't necessary.
3. Since the `(.*)` is greedy, it will match everything from here on up to the *last* "Note" in the text. I'm sure that's not what you want.
4. `\sNote` would match the word "Note" preceded by a space, but not (as in the example) the word "Note" *not* preceded by a space. Remove the `\s`.

Only when you correct all those errors will the regex work. Heed the disclaimers in the comments though.